# How is function in angular's api code checking for anonymous function signature getting multiple matches?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Working with the api code from angularjs. Interested in this function. **Not understanding how it is getting multiple matches.** For example in the return statement is uses args[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) vs arg[0].

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

function anonFn(fn) {
  // For anonymous functions, showing at the very least the function signature can help in
  // debugging.
  var fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, ''),
      args = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
  if (args) {
    return 'function(' + (args[1] || '').replace(/[\s\r\n]+/, ' ') + ')';
  }
  return 'fn';
}
```

So..

```
anonFn(function(a, b) { return a + b;}) 
// args = ["function (a, b)", "a, b", index: 0, input: "function (a, b) {return a + b;}"]
```

I understand args[2](http://www.regexr.com/3a45h) and on are a part of the standard out put if no global is set per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

But - **how is it returning both ["function (a, b)", "a, b",...] as the match case?**
First thought it was something i did not understand about Sting.prototype.match,
Now, think it is something I am not understanding about the regex - but

Did this check in RegExr [link](http://www.regexr.com/3a45h) and it is only showing matching - 'function(a, b)'

Other links: Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1w1LRRRupMWcyBEAJelG?p=options) and here is the src page angularjs api [anonFn](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/013b522c9e690665aecb0e0f656e4557a673ec09/src/auto/injector.js#L71)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns both whole match plus the characters inside group index 1. Because you defined a capturing group in your regex, it returns both matched characters as well as the chars inside the group index 1.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7pR2/4)

See at the right side in the above demo link. Your regex matches the string `function(a, b)` and also it captures the substring `a, b` because of capturing group. At last, the  corresponding function returns both the match and the captures.

Remove the capturing group from your regex and you must get only the matched string as output.

```
^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*[^\)]*\)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7pR2/5)

Comment: Thx for clear answer. So, when doing regex - you can use the idea of capturing groups to get additional substring results. Is that a good way to view it?  And I will start using that regex101 site looks pretty great.:)

Comment: yep, it's a good way , if you want the function to return the whole match plus the chars inside the paranthesis. Then you could access the single elements from the list by specifying it's index number.